# XNA Game Development Orbital Motion

Tags: optimization, xna, game-engine, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to develop game, which will take place in outer space. We decided to create a full 3D environment. Our goal is to create infinite world - it creates itself automatically when needed. One of our problems is how to create orbital movement of planets in the optimal way. There will be hundreds of them and calculating their new position in every frame sounds really expensive.

We have two ideas how to deal with it:

1. Calculate every position in a circuit (depends on time) after creating a planet and then during the game just read it from memory. However it sounds like a great waste of memory.
2. Calculate their movement only if they are in camera vision range. But it creates another problem with collision detection with other objects when off-screen.

My question is: does anybody know how it should be done? I wonder whether we shall focus on CPU or memory usage optimisation?

Comment: Best way if to try it, if it is only _hundreds_, it should be fine, you'd be surprised.